# Is there a way to get the current key of a rendered ListView Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wondering if it's possible to get the Key of a currently rendered widget in a `ListView.Builder()` generated list?

I have a `ListView.Builder`, that is simply building with widgets of `ListTile()`

```
ListTile(key: new PageStorageKey(index), title: new Text(CONTENT))
```

What I want to try to do is snoop on these keys as a user Scrolls, or suppose I trigger scrolling to occur programmatically, I could then watch the rendered keys of widgets to determine an appropriate stop point. Attempting to achieve scroll to index.

Comment: Your builder function is called eith the index, what would a key provide the index dorsn't?

Comment: Yes. What I am after is I would like to know where a user is in a very long list. My question is, how do I access the widget that is currently rendered on screen in a list view, and can I access the key or the index? currently displayed at the top of the viewport.